# ffmpeg overlay video on image and remove video black background

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, video-processing

Im using this ffmpeg command  to overlay a video on image (with remove black background):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -i video.mp4 -filter_complex [1:v]colorkey=0x000000:0.1:0.1[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[out] -map [out] -t 5 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -y result.mp4
```

[image]

But as you can see in the picture, the black parts of the ball have also disappeared. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Not possible with colorkey/chromakey alone. The background is too similar to the color you want to remove. You have two options.

## Mask

Use a mask. If the video comes with an alpha mask you can use it to cut out the background using the [alphamerge](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#alphamerge) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i bg.jpg -i video.mp4 -i alpha.mp4 -filter_complex "[1][2]alphamerge[alf];[0][alf]overlay" output.mp4
```

## Use a different color

Replace the video that has a color that is different than the color you want to remove.

Comment: Thank you :). now how to can generate alpha.mp4 from video.mp4 by cropping in a single command..

Comment: @MoslemAslani You can't. A mask or matte is rendered as a separate video from the source. It is grayscale, where white indicates opaque, and black is fully transparent. [Example](https://youtu.be/C79d59tsEiE). In your case the while football would be completely white. If the football does not move at all you can make a single image as a mask. See [this example](https://superuser.com/questions/901099/ffmpeg-apply-blur-over-face/901705#901705).